# Nmap not found when run from Python script

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, popen

I have written basic port scanner for target ip and when I run it through kali vm it says `sh: 1: nmap-F192.168.234.135: not found`. but when I run `nmap -F 192.168.234.135` ... its perfectly working. Can anyone point out the reason behind it. thanks

```
import os

def get_nmap(options,ip):
    command = "nmap" + options + "" + ip
    process = os.popen(command)
    result = str(process.read())
    return result

print(get_nmap('-F','192.168.234.135'))
```

Comment: ... "Writing a port scanner in python" isn't really just the process of invoking `nmap` via Python.

Comment: You need a space between options and IP. Change it to command = "nmap" + options + " " + ip

Comment: Maybe check out [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399626/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me/399627#399627), which will help you solve your underlying issue: ***If you aren't already a Linux pro, don't use Kali.*** This question is, frankly, totally baffling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better, using the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module:

```
def get_nmap(options, ip) :
    return subprocess.check_output(["nmap", options, ip])
#end get_nmap
```

Comment: I dont get how this is now the accepted answer. The question was already answered and this has nothing to do with why it was originaly not working.

Comment: It is better to avoid going through the shell when you don’t have to.

Comment: The OP asked for the reason why his code isn't working. This isn't an answer to that question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add spaces in the command string. Change it to

```
  command = "nmap " + options + " " + ip
```